# How to generate CMY triangle for the browser? (CSS, SVG, Canvas?)

Tags: css, canvas, svg, geometry

I am trying to produce a CMY triangle for a project. I would like to be able to render it directly on the web using either css, a svg or canvas.

Based on Amelia's comment, I tried building a CSS (SASS) class to render the triangle with linear-gradients.

```
.triangle {
  @include background-image(
linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 252, 253, 1), rgba(0, 252, 253, 0.25) 50%, rgba(0, 252, 253, 0) 86.6%),
linear-gradient(-60deg, rgba(250, 11, 247, 1), rgba(250, 11, 247, 0.25) 50%, rgba(250, 11, 247, 0) 86.6%),
linear-gradient(60deg, rgba(252, 249, 10, 1), rgba(252, 249, 10, 0.25) 50%, rgba(252, 249, 10, 0) 86.6%)
  );

  width: 300px;
  height: 260px;
}
```

I cannot apply this idea to a triangle using the usual technique of borders as it is applied to the background-image of the shape. Also, the blending appears to be off and the center point needs to be at the barycenter. I am not sure how I could solve this.

I am using d3.js to generate a SVG path for the triangle. Ideally, the solution could be applied to the "fill" property of the shape. I still could overlay and align the svg and the solution triangle if it is implemented another way.

One more complexity: Ideally, the triangle would not be exactly the usual CMY triangle. It would need to be more similar to the triangle below. Instead of varying linearly, each parameter would stay at 100% until half the "radius", and then drop to zero in the second half. There is also the K paramater that goes to zero in the center half.

Ideal triangle:

[image: Ideal triangle]

Normal CMY triangle:

[image: Normal CMY triangle]

Comment: That looks like it'll be a tough gradient to execute with CSS. Have you given it a try yet?

Comment: You'd be better of using canvas for this.

Comment: I doubt that a multidimensional gradient can be achieved with a single css gradient. As Robert already mentioned, canvas should work quite nicely here.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'll try with Canvas. Right now, I patched it using a png as a background-image (pattern) in a SVG path.

Comment: This is a very clear, focused question.  Maybe better suited on Graphic Design, but certainly on-topic for the CSS/SVG tags.  It isn't a debugging question at all, it is asking how to achieve a very specific effect.  I'd be happy to answer it if re-opened.  In the meantime, @maxim1500, you can probably figure it out from [this pen](http://codepen.io/AmeliaBR/pen/tkJCm); note that to really replicate the image in the question, you'd need to use [`background-blend-mode: screen`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-blend-mode).

Comment: I edited the message. Hopefully it will be reopened...

Comment: This is possible in SVG. I did a codepen http://codepen.io/mullany/pen/raeGKy/

Comment: Wow that is very cool. I adapted your solution to the CMY color space instead by inverting the colors. The only thing missing would be the black-ish color in the middle.  http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xbVWGj

Comment: You can try a component transfer to enhance contrast: http://codepen.io/mullany/pen/NPNMrX

Comment: And here's how to do a version that's compatible with legacy Firefox: http://codepen.io/mullany/pen/KwzBYZ - you have to draw the shapes in the body and overlay them using the filter.

Comment: The legacy version does not show on the ipad