# Smooth, interpolated tertiary or quaternary colour scales (e.g. r, g, b triangle) for matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors, color-space

Say I want to create a colour scheme for points in a matplotlib plot, and each point has a proportion of properties `A`, `B` and `C` (each of which can take values from 0 to 1). A simple way of doing this would be with an [rgb triangle](http://www.texample.net/media/tikz/examples/PNG/rgb-triangle.png), so that the point's red value is given by `A`, its green value is given by `B`, its blue value given by `C`.

However, it seems like maybe an alternative triangle like [this](http://www.allthesky.com/articles/preview/rgbtri.jpg) might give more 'dynamic range', i.e. make it easier to see where in the triangle each point is. However, I don't know how to code that specific triangle (i.e. given `A`, `B` and `C`, return a `(r,g,b)` tuple). It also has the additional problem of having white in the centre, which wouldn't appear well against a white background.

**My question:** What would be a good triangle colour scale for a problem like this? And what is this kind of thing called, because I'm finding it difficult to search for?

Additionally, if we wanted to extend this to four properties, `A`, `B`, `C` and `D`, and have a "colour square," what would be appropriate colours for the four corners, and how would you write a function to go from `A`, `B`, `C` and `D` and return a `(r,g,b)` tuple?

It seems like ideally a colour scheme like this (a) has unique colours everywhere, (b) doesn't have white in it, and (c) ideally has high variation to make it easier to see where in the colour scale you are by looking at it. Even better would be something colour blind safe, but in this circumstance that might be too much to ask for.

Advice very much appreciated. My end goal is to make something like [this](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/dpsanders/matplotlib-examples/blob/master/colorline.ipynb) but with one of these colour schemes. Thanks.

Edit: Adding the important constraint `A+B+C=1` to make this technically possible. For the sake of example, let's say I want to come up with a colour scheme so that a unique colour maps to a specific composition in a [ternary phase diagram such as this](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/6/61/TernaryExample.svg/800px-TernaryExample.svg.png). The 'obvious' case is to use a RGB triangle, but is there a better solution? And how would I code that in Python?

Comment: In a nutshell, you're asking about different "color spaces". Have a look here for starters: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_space

Comment: Thanks. I've actually tried searching for colour spaces, but mostly get results about monitor calibrations and that sort of thing, not the help I need to write a function that actually goes from `A`, `B`, `C` to the `(r,g,b)` tuple I need...

Comment: I'm thinking perhaps a triangle with C-M-Y corners (maybe with subtractive mixing, I'm not sure) might work well, but I'm not sure how to code that? like perhaps one of the triangles in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27450249/how-to-generate-cmy-triangle-for-the-browser-css-svg-canvas)

Comment: The problem with any of those triangles is that they don't account for all possibilities. In fact, I don't think you can represent all possibilities in a triangle like that. Either you leave out the case where A = 1, B = 1, C = 1 or A = 0, B = 0, C = 0. You'd need a 3D plot to show all the colors, or maybe a really convoluted 2D one.

Comment: @AmyTeegarden, very true. Thanks. I should have added an additional constraint. Let's say `A+B+C=1`. Then we can have something like a [ternary phase diagram](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/6/61/TernaryExample.svg/800px-TernaryExample.svg.png), which is more like what I'm after really. So a colour scale that would map to a given point in that diagram.

Comment: Don't worry about RGB being three-dimensional: that's presumably what you want to do, put as much distinct information as possible on the page. It's a problem when you're trying to print the color space but not when you're using it.

Comment: [ColorBrewer](http://colorbrewer2.org/) has some good discussions of how we interpret different color maps. Really we can't generically choose a best colormap without knowing what your data is and what features need to be most visible.

Comment: Thanks @cphlewis. I've had a look at ColorBrewer, but they're all binary colour schemes, rather than ternary, unless I'm misunderstanding? For argument's sake let's say I want to represent a composition in a ternary phase diagram (see the link in my previous comment), and map a unique colour to each composition in that triangle.

Comment: @Matthew, I wasn't suggesting that you couldn't use a particular mapping, just that the triangles you show don't tell the whole story. If you want to avoid white in your colorspace, you can always multiply A, B, and C by .75 so you won't get white even when they're all 1. So your function would just return (.75 * A, .75 * B, .75 * C).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, I've given this a go. It's not perfect and is a bit of a hack, so improvements/suggested are very much welcomed. I'd be happy to accept a better answer (in particular improvements to `abc_to_rgb` either to remove errors, improve dynamic range, or just a better colour scheme for colour blindness). I was thinking about maybe using the [YIQ colour space with Y=0.5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YIQ#/media/File:YIQ_IQ_plane.svg) for an equivalent quaternary colour scheme (square legend). Also, this is the first time I've used barycentric co-ordinates, so my plotting of the legend is probably not ideal (a better legend might not 'bleed' out of the edges, for example, or need so many points).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import math

def abc_to_rgb(A=0.0,B=0.0,C=0.0):
    ''' Map values A, B, C (all in domain [0,1]) to
    suitable red, green, blue values.'''
    return (min(B+C,1.0),min(A+C,1.0),min(A+B,1.0))

def plot_legend():
    ''' Plots a legend for the colour scheme
    given by abc_to_rgb. Includes some code adapted
    from http://stackoverflow.com/a/6076050/637562'''

    # Basis vectors for triangle
    basis = np.array([[0.0, 1.0], [-1.5/np.sqrt(3), -0.5],[1.5/np.sqrt(3), -0.5]])

    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111,aspect='equal')

    # Plot points
    a, b, c = np.mgrid[0.0:1.0:50j, 0.0:1.0:50j, 0.0:1.0:50j]
    a, b, c = a.flatten(), b.flatten(), c.flatten()

    abc = np.dstack((a,b,c))[0]
    #abc = filter(lambda x: x[0]+x[1]+x[2]==1, abc) # remove points outside triangle
    abc = map(lambda x: x/sum(x), abc) # or just make sure points lie inside triangle ...

    data = np.dot(abc, basis)
    colours = [abc_to_rgb(A=point[0],B=point[1],C=point[2]) for point in abc]

    ax.scatter(data[:,0], data[:,1],marker=',',edgecolors='none',facecolors=colours)

    # Plot triangle
    ax.plot([basis[_,0] for _ in range(3) + [0,]],[basis[_,1] for _ in range(3) + [0,]],**{'color':'black','linewidth':3})

    # Plot labels at vertices
    offset = 0.25
    fontsize = 32
    ax.text(basis[0,0]*(1+offset), basis[0,1]*(1+offset), '$A$', horizontalalignment='center',
            verticalalignment='center', fontsize=fontsize)
    ax.text(basis[1,0]*(1+offset), basis[1,1]*(1+offset), '$B$', horizontalalignment='center',
            verticalalignment='center', fontsize=fontsize)
    ax.text(basis[2,0]*(1+offset), basis[2,1]*(1+offset), '$C$', horizontalalignment='center',
            verticalalignment='center', fontsize=fontsize)    

    ax.set_frame_on(False)
    ax.set_xticks(())
    ax.set_yticks(())

    plt.show()
```

This gives our legend as follows:

[image: Example ternary colour legend.]

And then `abc_to_rgb` can be used to get a suitable colour for a given point in a scatter or line graph...

Comment: Nice and clear. Bug-hunting: Why does the edge outside the AB border not quite match the colors inside?

Comment: I couldn't tell you precisely, but any point `A+B+C>1` is valid, it just lies outside the triangle, and the function `abc_to_rgb` doesn't check for any constraints on `A`,`B` and `C`. However, I did restrict all points to being inside the triangle, but on my computer the 'pixel' markers for matplotlib are appearing as squares, meaning they bleed outside the triangle edges. So I'm not sure where the bug is exactly. Additionally, this question raised another question for me: how do you generate a 'uniform' grid for barycentric co-ordinates (that is a list of `(a,b,c)` tuples where `a+b+c=1`)?

Answer (score 1):

Play around with something like this to see how to represent your own data:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy import random

count = 300
space = random.random((count,2))
hue = random.uniform(0,1,(count,3))

def to_rgb(triplet):
    '''convert a triplet of values in the range [0,1]
    to a RGB triplet of values in the range [0, 255] (integers);
    blue is kept to a smaller range so the RGB never turns white.'''

    red = triplet[0]
    green = 1-triplet[1]
    blue = triplet[2]*0.75

    return [red, green, blue]


plt.scatter(space[:,0], space[:,1], c=map(to_rgb, hue), s=60)
plt.show()
```

You can use the ColorBrewer discussions of how we interpret monochrome or diverging or whatever color schemes to figure out how you want to represent each of the three "color" variables. (It is harder to represent three of them in combination. Harder yet to do it in a way that works for even the most common colorblindness.)

Comment: Thanks for the response but this isn't quite what I was looking for, I've posted an alternative answer.